# Code never enter any of the if statements

Tags: ruby, chomp

```
begin
  selected_option = gets.chomp
  if selected_option == 1
    puts "Welcome to the Welcome Screen!"
  elsif selected_option == 2
    puts "This is the options menu."
  elsif selected_option == 3
    puts "Logging out. Goodbye!"
  else
    puts "Please select a valid option."
  end  
end while not selected_option == 3
```

I enter in 1 or 2 or 3 and I always get the "Please enter a valid option" message. I'm guessing that's because the chomp method retrieves the input as a string.

Any way around this sans using quotes around the options?

Comment: @Gareve: My computer just formatted the C drive. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio: You should file that as a bug.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, there is no way that IRB or '1 == "1"' in IRB would format a hard drive. If that happened, it was entirely unrelated.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I was kidding of course.

Comment: I laughed. But now my Mac appears to be hung trying to format some non-existent "C:" drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gets.chomp.to_i
```

Will convert it to an integer.

You may also want to use a switch instead:

```
begin
  selected_option = gets.chomp.to_i
  case selected_option
    when 1
      puts "Welcome to the Welcome Screen!"
    when 2
      puts "This is the options menu."
    when 3
      puts "Logging out. Goodbye!"
    else
      puts "Please select a valid option."
  end  
end while not selected_option == 3
```

Comment: Aha! Solid. Let me test this out.

Comment: And much better with a switch.